# How solve this error in cakephp3.0 ?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in D:\Hosting\12807605\html******\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 107

Comment: Could you provide the bootstrap.php source code with specifically line 107?

Answer (score 1):

Need PHP 5.4.16 or greater. Please Try This,Its will help you.

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#

In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.
In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working. To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default) C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code in PHP 5.4+ as shown in the requirements list for the framework.